How to connect to Websocket deployed on AWS ECS
I have a FastAPI websocket that I deployed as a Docker Image on AWS ECS. I have created a task definition, a service that use Fargate and a Load Balancer that acts on the 80 port since I use HTTP and also run the FastAPI server on that port.
I tried connecting to the websocket through wscat -c but I get an empty error. I was wondering if I need to perform any additional changes to allow the connection to the websocket in AWS.
Let me know if you have any ideas, many thanks!
